# Writing an XML rule parser in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have a complex xml file which has multi-level elements. I have to parse the XML file and based on the elements present, I have to handle the incoming request. I can use JAXB to generate the classes and parse the xml. But to go through the multi-level elements and match against the rules makes the program too complex and heavy (leads to 4-5 levels of loops). Is there an efficient and lighter way of achieving the same?

Comment: Please demonstrate 4-5 levels of loops which cause the problem. As it stands now, it is not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs to store -or not- temporarily the read data, you can count on these parsers:

- DOM (Document Object Model) parsers store the XML data into a memory structure.
- jDOM (Java DOM) parser is a DOM-like implementation in Java, with its own API.
- SAX (Simple API for XML) parsers traverse an XML stream completely asynchronously, throwing user events for every read data.
- StAX (Streaming API for XML) parsers reads an XML stream synchronously.

All of them can be found in any standard runtime (JRE), except jDOM, which is open-source.

So, if you are looking for an efficient way to process XML and take decissions based upon the read data, maybe StAX would suit your needs, because as soon as you get the data you need, you might stop reading and discard the rest of the input XML.

### Update

To apply matching rules over the whole document I recommend you to use XPath over DOM.

Comment: The issue is not in parsing the xml file. The real problem is to traverse through the parsed XML, checking for tags and attributes and taking actions based on them. Since there are multiple levels of elements, the code gets 5-6 levels of loops and becomes very brittle.

Comment: Must you process **the whole** XML, or just some selected data in order to take further decissions?

Comment: No, I have to parse the whole xml, and based on the elements present I have call different functions.

Comment: OK. Have you though about using XPATH?